# String extraction & formatting for SQL snippet execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I have a few parameters typed in a string that need to be extracted & substituted using the string `format()` function. The code snippet is as follows:

```
# Filter list (output from another script)
filters ='recipient_id=100, reporting_date=2020-10-12'

# Fetch SQL file from location
sql_file = 'configs/sql_files/{sql_name}.sql'.format(sql_name=sql_name)
file_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
final_file_path = "/".join(file_path.split("/")[:-2]) + "/" + sql_file

with open(final_file_path) as sql_file:
    # Pass in filters to the SQL snippet. The SQL snippet has two parameters
    # recipient_id & reporting_date
    sql = sql_file.read().format(filters)

try:
     sf = get_sql_client()
except Exception as e:
     print("Error connecting to the DB!")
     sys.exit()

df = sf.fetch_df(sql)
```

The code snippet fails as "filters" is being passed as a string.

```
sql_file.read().format('recipient_id=100, reporting_date=2020-10-12')
```

Instead, it should be passed as below:

```
sql_file.read().format(recipient_id=100, reporting_date='2020-10-12')
```

Is there a way to extract the "filters" string & format it as above?

SQL file sample:

```
    SELECT columns..
FROM A
join B on <condition>
WHERE true
   AND REPORTING_LEVEL_1_ID = '{recipient_id}'  
   AND date_trunc('day', delivered_date_pt) >= DATEADD(day, -7, last_day('{reporting_date}'::date, 'week') + 1)
   AND date_trunc('day', delivered_date_pt) <= last_day('{reporting_date}'::date, 'week')
```

Comment: Does the contents of  the string returned by `sql_file.read()` have the brace characters,`{` and `}`, in it in the proper places to work in conjunction with the string `format()` method? Please [edit] your question and show an example of what's in the sql file being read.

Comment: @martineau updated it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try using double quotes like so...

```
filters ="recipient_id=100, reporting_date='2020-10-12'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sql file with contents like that and for filtering information formatting as shown (as a series of name and value pairs, separated by comma and space characters), you could create dictionary from the latter and then pass it to the `format()` method as shown (using a `**` prefix to unpack the items in it).

```
filter_data = 'recipient_id=100, reporting_date=2020-10-12'
final_file_path = 'sql_file'

with open(final_file_path) as sql_file:
    pairs = (pair.split('=') for pair in filter_data.replace(',', '').split())
    mapping = {k: v for (k, v) in pairs}
    sql = sql_file.read().format(**mapping)
    print(sql)
```

Output:

```sql
SELECT columns..
FROM A
join B on <condition>
WHERE true
   AND REPORTING_LEVEL_1_ID = '100'
   AND date_trunc('day', delivered_date_pt) >= DATEADD(day, -7, last_day('2020-10-12'::date, 'week') + 1)
   AND date_trunc('day', delivered_date_pt) <= last_day('2020-10-12'::date, 'week')
```

Comment: user14255754: Isn't this what you wanted to do?